# WebSockets server that will complete the job after the connection is made - Ruby, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use something like EventMachine websockets to push status updates to the client as they happen.

My application crawls round a section of a website screen scraping relevant details of a user's search.  I want to push any screen scraping captures to the client as they happen.  I also want to persist these changes to the database.  I also want the job to complete even if the user closes down the browser.

At the moment, the job is initiated from the client (browser) and the job is placed on a resque queue that completes the job.  The client polls the database and displays the results.

I want to have a play around with websockets but I don't think I can get the same behaviour.  It is more important that the results are persisted and the job completes than the real time pushes.

Am I wrong in the assumption that this cannot be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at faye. [Masseging With Faye(RailsCasts)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye). You can keep on using the rescue queue to get the job completed and push the  message to subscriber(your web client) as and when you find the results.

Comment: Ideally, I would somehow like to pass the items back from the resque queue handler after they are added to the database.  Is it possible to use callbacks or something from the resque queue handler?

Comment: Sorry mate, I have hadn't have any experience with rescue. Delayed jobs fits my needs for now. But you can have after_save callbacks or an observer if you want to push the results after saving to database.